# QRegExp getting Duplication in Debug Result

Tags: qt, qregexp, qregularexpression

**My Code is :**

```
QString strExp="Sum(2+3)-Sum(5+3)";

QRegExp regexp("(Sum\\([^)]*\\))");
regexp.indexIn(strExp);

QStringList lst=regexp.capturedTexts();
qDebug()<<"CapturedCounts:"<<regexp.captureCount();

qDebug()<<lst;
```

I have getting captured count is 1 and qstring
 list debug output as shown below

```
("Sum(2+3)", "Sum(2+3)").
```

Why?

Answer (score 2):

The first element of the `QRegExp::capturedTexts()` list is the entire matched string.

[The doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qregexp.html#capturedTexts) says:

> `QStringList QRegExp::capturedTexts() const`
>
> Returns a list of the captured text strings.
>
> The first string in the list is the entire matched string. Each
>   subsequent list element contains a string that matched a (capturing)
>   subexpression of the regexp.

Another example:

```
QString s = "abcd123";
QRegExp re("(ab).*(12)");

qDebug() << "indexIn:" << re.indexIn(s);
qDebug() << "captureCount:" << re.captureCount();
qDebug() << "capturedTexts:" << re.capturedTexts();
```

Output will be:

```
indexIn: 0 
captureCount: 2 
capturedTexts: ("abcd12", "ab", "12")
```

If you want to get all matches, you can use this:

```
QString strExp="Sum(2+3)-Sum(5+3)";

QRegExp regexp("(Sum\\([^)]*\\))");
regexp.indexIn(strExp);

QStringList list;
int pos = 0;

while ((pos = regexp.indexIn(strExp, pos)) != -1) {
    list << regexp.cap(1);
    pos += regexp.matchedLength();
}

qDebug() << "all matches:" << list;
```

Output:

```
all matches: ("Sum(2+3)", "Sum(5+3)")
```

Comment: in My examble,How can be extract that types of  in Qt

Comment: *that types of expressions

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: How can parseQString strExp="Sum(2+3)-Sum(5+3)";

QRegExp regexp("(Sum\\([^)]*\\))")

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding questions. I need to know about qt class for parse arithmatic expression like  a*(b+c) and sum(a+b)

Comment: There is no such class in Qt.

Comment: is there any way with out loop.